# Uploading file to third party server with IP range filtering from Google Container Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We need to upload reports from a pod deployed on Kubernetes on Google Container Engine to a third party server that is protected by a firewall that enforce IP range filtering. Google’s IP range is dynamic (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#ipranges)) so I cannot tell their operations team to simply open up a fixed IP range. How can we work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since VMs have static IPs over their lifetime, you could provision a "bastion" VM in your project and use it to tunnel your uploads:

1. Whitelist the external IP for the bastion machine in the third party server.
2. Configure a proxy on the bastion machine to forward requests from your pod to the third party server (ignoring requests that aren't coming from IP addresses that are in your cluster's address range).
3. Point your report uploader at the IP of the bastion machine.

This leaves the bastion as a single point of failure, so if you wanted some redundancy you could set up a few of them (in different regions).

Comment: I think we need something like HaProxy since we need to upload our reports using SFTP. Do you know if there already exists HaProxy "utilities"/plugins that knows how whitelist a Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: I don't but there might be one that knows how to whitelist by source IP (which should be sufficient).

Comment: Hmm the IP addresses of a K8S cluster are dynamic (machines can come and go) so I don't see how that can be sufficient?

Comment: The cluster should have a fixed range (a /14 for GKE and [10.244.0.0/16 for GCE](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/gce/config-default.sh#L53) unless you changed the default) that is fixed, even if each pod's IP address can change.

Comment: Oh I didn't know this. Thanks! Btw, do you know if this is documented somewhere?

Comment: The closest I see is the description for `clusterIpv4Cidr` on https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.zones.clusters#Cluster